# Fetching movie data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ajax

- Requirements

  - Display movie datas inside all tags that have the class movie_list
  - Make an ajax call for fetching movie datas
  - Fill loading text before fetch data
  - If any error occurs during loading, the content should be empty
- What I did

  - Cached all elements which have the class movie_list
  - Made functions which have only one responsibility
  - Functions take movieList elements for making easy to unit test
- What I want to know

  - More readable/reusable code
  - Any performance improvement point
  - Any good design pattern on here

```
function loadMovies() {
   const url = 'http://moviedatas.com/movies';
   const movieList = $('.movie_list');

   setOnLoading(movieList);

   $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url: url,
       data: {
           count: 10
       },
       success: function(response) {
           movieList.each(function() {
               const wrapper = $(this);

               render(wrapper, items);
           });
       },
       error: function(error) {
           onError(movieList);
       }
   })
}

function setOnLoading(movieList) {
   movieList.each(function() {
       $(this).html('Loading...');
   });
}

function render(wrapper, items) {
   const template = `<div class="movie_item">
 <div class="title">{title}</div>
 <div class="desc">{description}</div>
</div>`;

   let movies = '';
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       movies += template
           .replace('{title}', items[i].title)
           .replace('{description}', items[i].description);
   }

   wrapper.html(movies);
}

function onError(movieList) {
   movieList.each(function() {
       $(this).html('');
   });
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you are iterating a movie list (array of elements) passing what is presumably a list of movie titles/descriptions to each, yet there is no reference to `items` in `render(wrapper, items);`? Nor does the code make semantic sense, it reads as creating a movie list of movie lists?? You will have to clarify and fix the code to get a good review.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by **Blindman67**: in `render(wrapper, items);`, `items` is not defined.

1. > ```
   > const url = 'http://moviedatas.com/movies';
   > ```

   Const variable used only one time, you can remove it and write `url: http://moviedatas.com/movies`

   Same for

   ```
   const wrapper = $(this);
   ```
2. Use ES6 arrow function shortcut syntax `() =>`

   > ```
   >     success: function(response) {
   >         movieList.each(function() {
   >             const wrapper = $(this);
   >
   >             render(wrapper, items);
   >         });
   >     },
   > ```

   7 lines in one, shorter is cleaner.

   ```
   success: (response) => movieList.each(() => render($(this), response.items)),
   ```
3. > ```
   > error: function(error) {
   >     onError(movieList);
   > }
   > ```

   If you don't use `error` XHR response, just write

   ```
   error: () => onError(movieList)
   ```
4. Write [jsDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html) docstring above functions to help developers and IDE understanding what is happening.
5. If functions are becoming inline, you may write them directly in caller function.

### Full review (without docstring)

```js
function loadMovies() {
   const movieList = $('.movie_list');

   // setOnLoading
   movieList.each(() => $(this).html('Loading...'));

   $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url    : 'http://moviedatas.com/movies',
       data   : { count: 10 },
       success: (response) => movieList.each(() => render($(this), response.items))
       error  : () => movieList.each(() => $(this).html(''));
   });
}

function render(wrapper, items) {
   const template = `<div class="movie_item">
     <div class="title">{title}</div>
     <div class="desc">{description}</div>
    </div>`;

   let movies = '';

   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       movies += template
           .replace('{title}', items[i].title)
           .replace('{description}', items[i].description);
   }

   wrapper.html(movies);
}
```

Also, I don't understand the logic of getting a movie list data and then iterating over a movie list HTML to put movies in. It becomes a list of list of movies...

Answer (score 2):

The code already uses some [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like the `const` and `let` keywords and template literals.

Another ES-6 feature that could be used is the [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to simplify blocks like this:

> ```
> for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
>     movies += template
>         .replace('{title}', items[i].title)
>         .replace('{description}', items[i].description);
> }
> ```

To this:

```
for (const item of items) {
    movies += template
        .replace('{title}', item.title)
        .replace('{description}', item.description);
}
```

---

The error handler could be simplified using a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions), to avoid an extra function call - i.e.

> ```
> error: function(error) {
>     onError(movieList);
> }
> ```

Can be simplified to:

```
error: onError.bind(null, movieList)
```